# Difference between text and textContent properties

Tags: javascript, dom, anchor

According to the [HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-a-element)  and the [DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) an [`HTMLAnchorElement`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-a-element) has a `text` and a `textContent` property. What is the purpose of the `text` property? As far as I can tell `text` is just a read-only getter for `textContent`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) property is "inhertied" from the [Node interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) of the DOM Core specification. The [text](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-a-text) property is "inherited" from the HTML5 [HTMLAnchorElement interface](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#htmlanchorelement) and is specified as "must return the same value as the textContent IDL attribute".

The two are probably retained to converge different browser behaviour, the [text property for script elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-script-text) is defined slightly differently.

Note that the DOM specification is a general specification for any kind of document (e.g. HTML, XML, SGML, etc.) whereas HTML5 is specifically for HTML that leverages and extends the DOM Core in many respects (some might say it's a "super set" of a few DOM specs plus HTML plus …).

Note that "inherited" does not mean "prototype inheritance", just the more general meaning of inherited.

Comment: Is there any purpose to `text` then? Since HTML is an extension of the  DOM Core I can't imagine any scenario which you could use `text` over `textContent`

Comment: In DOM 2 HTML, only 4 elements had a text property and it did different things (e.g. for [body](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-73714763) it was the document text colour, for [title](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-77500413) it was the title text, also [option](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-48154426) and [script](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46872999)). But support was inconsistent, HTML5 seems to be trying to converge text with textContent. It is as much about "what browsers actually do" as "what they should do".

Comment: if `text` and `textContent` are the same then I'd use `text` as it's shorter.

Comment: I am using the XML DOM in IE11, and it seems to only have a textContent property, and no text property. So to be consistent between the XML DOM and HTML DOM, it seems to make sense to always use textContent.

Comment: In a list with an option like `foo<space><space><space>bar`, that list.options[i].tex returns `foo<space>bar` and list.options[i].textContent returned `foo<space><space><space>bar`. Unfortunantely it looks like .text just not giving me a string with multiple whitespaces. => <space> stands for a whitespace

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `textContent` as seen on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [W3C quirksmode.org](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/)

The `text` property you referenced from [DOM Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-text), refers to the [Text Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)