# using document.querySelector to get a value/name from a website

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the value of the 'a' tag from a website. I'm running the code below in the console of Google Chrome.

```js
document.querySelector('#container > article:nth-child(1) > div > h1 > a');
```

Executing that returns this tag:

```html
<a class="name-link" href="/shop/blarg/foo/bar">blarg</a>
```

I'm trying to get 'blarg' returned, preferably in a variable. I have tried the following:

```js
document.querySelector('#container > article:nth-child(1) > div > h1 > a').value;
```

However it simply returns 'undefined'. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. To get innner text instead of `.value` you should use `.text`

```
document.querySelector('#container > article:nth-child(1) > div > h1 > a').text;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any difference from using this and .textContent?

Comment: @aboruchovas Read this for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172461/5147832

Answer (score 3):

You should select innerHTML

```
document.querySelector('#container > article:nth-child(1) > div > h1 > a').innerHTML;
```

You can also edit that html like this

```
document.querySelector('#container > article:nth-child(1) > div > h1 > a').innerHTML="new value";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the textContent property to get the text as a tag does not have an value property and will return undefined

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#container > article:nth-child(1) > div > h1 > a').textContent);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <article>
      <div>
        <h1>
          <a class="name-link" href="/shop/blarg/foo/bar">blarg</a> 
        </h1>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great thank you! Is there any difference in using this as opposed to .text instead?

Comment: They are almost the same just inherited from different objects

Answer (score 2):

Use `innerHTML` instead of value.
i.e.

```
document.querySelector('#container > article:nth-child(1) > div > h1 > a').innerHTML;
```

`querySelector` returns the first web page element (object) that matches the specified group of selectors. So you can not use **value** with the return result of querySelector.